# Qt project in visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

Can anybody tell me where I should declare my GUI elements for example `QPushbutton`, in my Qt project on VS 2010 :
Let's say the project name is : Qtapp. so I'll get :

```
  Qtapp.h
  Qtapp.cpp
  main.cpp
  ui_qtapp
```

where should I declare my variables and SLOTs and where should I connect them to each other .
thanks in advance

Comment: You declare your slots in Qtapp.h and connect them in Qtapp.cpp

Comment: Alfter that make sure you have moc working and that the generated moc source is included in your project.

Comment: Why no just use QtCreator its so much easier to make Qt programs in.

Comment: because I want to understand what exactly happens there